# How to get groups matching pattern except special cases

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to get all the :randomtext: templates from string except `<:randomtext:123>` and `<a:randomtext:123>` cases and replace them with another string. How can I get all these groups?

#### Attempt

```
[^<](:\w+?:)
```

Here's my [demo](https://regex101.com/r/T5tqZY/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example data, you could match what you don't want and capture what you do want. You could capture between the brackets containing at least a `:`

```
<.*?:.*?>|(:\w+:)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2sRBT7/1)

Or if you don't want to match brackets in between, you could use a negated character class `[^<>]` to match not an opening or closing bracket.

```
<[^<>]*:[^<>]*>|(:\w+:)
```

- `<` Match < char
- `[^<>]*` Negated character class, match not < or > 0+ times
- `:` Match :
- `[^<>]*` Negated character class, match not < or > 0+ times
- `>` Match > char
- `|` Or
- `(:\w+:)` Capture in group 1 matching 1+ word characters between :

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bul34n/1)

```js
const regex = /<[^<>]*:[^<>]*>|(:\w+:)/gm;
const str = `:fra: :fra: <:fra:12312312> <a:fra:!232131> :fra::fra:
Some text:fra: Hello:fra::fra::fra: :fra:`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  if (undefined !== m[1]) {
    console.log(m[1]);
  }
}
```

If you want to [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Parameters) the matches `:fra:` with `new` you could switch the capturing groups and make use of replace with a callback.

```js
const regex = /(<[^<>]*:[^<>]*>)|:\w+:/gm;
let str = `:fra: :fra: <:fra:12312312> <a:fra:!232131> :fra::fra:
Some text:fra: Hello:fra::fra::fra: :fra:`;

str = str.replace(regex, function(m, g1) {
  return undefined === g1 ? "new" : m;

});
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I dont need data inside `<>` brackets, how can I exclude them from match?

Comment: @Vladimir I have added a Javscript demo.

Comment: Can you please add an example how can I replace these matched groups with another string after that?

Comment: So you want to keep your current text and leave the text between the `<>` untouched, but add a string after captured strings like :test: newstring

Comment: Yeah, replace these :test: strings with new.

Comment: @Vladimir I have added an example how to do the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that here we just want a simple expression,

```
(?:<.*?)(:.*?:)(?:.+?>)
```

to be replaced with anything that we want.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YjcoGI/1)

```js
const regex = /(?:<.*?)(:.*?:)(?:.+?>)/gmi;
const str = `:fra: :fra: <:fra:12312312> <a:fra:!232131> :fra::fra:
Some text:fra: Hello:fra::fra::fra: :fra:`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: I need all `:text:` except these `<:text:>` groups

Comment: I need only the ones with `:text:` pattern, not the `<:text:>` ones

Comment: Sorry but no, probably I'm bad at explanation. I need all the `:fra:` from text without `<>` braces.

Comment: Your expression gets all the templates inside `<>` brackets, but these are the ones I don't need. I need only templates that are without brackets and not inside them.